# Elasticsearch index for searching

Tags: elasticsearch

With the following index, on `metricname_text`, lets say we have a document that contains the string `1048avg_percent_memory_used`. I am finding that if I type `1048` for the search result, I will find it. However, if I type `percent_memory`, it will not find any results. Can someone point me in the right direction on the correct index to use to partially match a word, but not necessarily anchored from the beginning of the word? I am also not sure if I `match` query is the correct search type to use.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {

      "filter": {
          "autocomplete_filter": { 
              "type":     "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram": 1,
              "max_gram": 20
          }
      },

      "analyzer": {
          "autocomplete": {
              "type":      "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard",
              "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "autocomplete_filter" 
              ]
          }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "metric": {
      "properties": {
        "metricname_text": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete"
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
metadata = {
  "settings": {
      "analysis": {
          "filter": {
              "trigrams_filter": {
                  "type":     "ngram",
                  "min_gram": 3,
                  "max_gram": 3
              }
          },
          "analyzer": {
              "trigrams": {
                  "type":      "custom",
                  "tokenizer": "standard",
                  "filter":   [
                      "lowercase",
                      "trigrams_filter"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "metric": {
      "properties": {
        "metricname_text": {
            "type":     "text",
            "analyzer": "trigrams"
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```